# get data in my dropdown btn does not work

Tags: php, html

I am not able to return the property status using the ternary operator

this is my code

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="imo_status">STATUS DO IMÓVEL</label>
                                <div class="form-line">
                                                
                                    <select class="form-control" id="imo_status" name="imo_status">
                                        <option value="">Selecione o Status</option>
                                        <option <?= (isset($imo_status) ? $imo_status : set_value('imo_status')) == '1' ? 'selected' : '' ?> value="Ativo">Ativo</option>
                                        <option <?= (isset($imo_status) ? $imo_status : set_value('imo_status')) == '0' ? 'selected' : '' ?> value="Inativo">Inativo</option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here it should return the option 1 = active

[image]

Comment: try adding code as text

Comment: it seem you have php error that makes the dropdown is not visible as html code. Try open the page in source view to see what error is there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what PHP version you are using. But the inline `if` with character `x ? y : z` cannot be use twice without bracket. Try this one:

```
<option <?= isset($imo_status) ? $imo_status : (set_value('imo_status') == '1' ? "selected" : "")  ?> >Active</option>
```

## Editted

Sorry i read the code wrongly. Actually you need to see whether the method `set_value()` has return any value or not and what value they set to.

Try debug with `print_r($imo_status)` and `print_r(set_value('imo_status'))` to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this

```
<select class="form-control" id="imo_status" name="imo_status">
                                        <option value="1"<?=$properties['imo_status'] == '1' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>Ativo</option>
                                        <option value="0"<?=$properties['imo_status'] == '0' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>Inativo</option>
                                    </select>
```